# My anchor text not clickable all of a sudden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, anchor

It was all working just fine. I was fine tuning some css. Then I tried clicking on a link and it didn't work and neither did the a:hover selector, but they had before.

I have ran it through both the HTML5 and CSS3 validators and all is well there.

Could someone please take a look to see if I'm missing anything?

The url that I'm having problems with is http://www.realproagent.com both the *seller* and *buyer* links in the middle of the page. The homepage and feedback link at the bottom seems to be fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Jquery library file link dead.

http://www.realproagent.com/jquery.js File not found

[image]

check console

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've killed your jQuery reference. Chrome Console shows:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.realproagent.com/jquery.js
>   
>   
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined